# Explaining why $T$ is linear and finding the matrix $A$ such that $T(v) = Av$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}y\\x\end{bmatrix}$
>
> $S: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}xy\\1\end{bmatrix}$
>
> a) Explain why $T$ is linear and find the matrix $A$ such that $T(v) = Av$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$
>
> b) Explain why $S$ is not linear

a) I know that $T$ is linear because $T(0) = \begin{bmatrix}(0)\\(0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} = 0$

But what is the process in "*find the matrix* $A$ *such that* $T(v) = Av$ *for all* $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$"

b) Can't I just do $S(0) = \begin{bmatrix}(0)(0)\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} \ne 0 \implies$ **not** linear?

Comment: your first argument is false but the second is true

Comment: $T$ linear means that $T(u+\alpha v)=T(u)+\alpha T(v)$

Comment: @Hamza What? If $T(0) = 0$ then the transformation is linear

Comment: Sending the zero vector to the zero vector is a necessary condition for a linear map, but **not sufficient**. So you are done with b), but not with a) (even without considering the question of a matrix)

Comment: So are you saying instead it should say $T(0) = T(y) + T(x) = T(0) + T(0) = 0$?

Comment: $T(x)=x^2$ send $0$ to $0$ but he is not linear in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: No, you should consider whether $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(\lambda x)=\lambda T(x)$, or something equivalent to that.

Comment: Yea, elaborate @MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y)$ is exactly what I just said above... Then I just plugged in 0 for $x$ and $y$

Comment: You want it to be true for all vectors, just not $x=y=0$.

Comment: The only vectors I have is $x$ and $y$? @TonyS.F.

Comment: You are picking specific values for $x$ and $y$, namely $x=y=0$. You want show the transform is linear for all possible values of $x$ and $y$, not just $x=y=0$.

Comment: Wait, do you mean i need to set some scalar $a =b = 0$ @TonyS.F.

Comment: @Yusha  No, you also had the zero vector there.  Linearity is defined without using the zero vector.  It is defined exactly the way Tony S. F. said, and that's what should be checked.  Linearity means two properties: sums are preserved (i.e., whatever the vectors $x, y$, one always has $T(x+y) = Tx + Ty$, and scalar multiples are preserved: $T(\alpha x) = \alpha Tx$ for all scalars $\alpha$ and all vectors $x$.

For your transformation $S$, just find one specific vector that violates either (or both) of the above, and that will prove $S$ nonlinear.

Comment: @Yusha, it is true, however, that *if* a transformation is linear, *then* it will map the zero vector to the zero vector.

Comment: @avs Yea, I've already established that in the OP. I know that S is not linear because $S(0) \ne 0$. They are saying that my part $a$ is incorrect to show that $T$ is linear though

Comment: And they are right.  For example, the transformation $Q : [x, y, z] \rightarrow [x^2, yz]$ satisfies $Q([0,0,0]) = [0,0]$, but fails to be linear.

Comment: It seems like you might be confused about the for all part of the definition of linear and I recommend reviewing proofs involving quantifiers like "for all".

Comment: @JeffL., Yes, I suspect that, too.

Yusha, try to prove that the sum of any three consecutive integers is always divisible by three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $T$ is linear in fact let $u=(x,y,z)$ and $v=(a,b,c)$ two vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ a scalar so : 
\begin{align}
T(\alpha u+v)=T(\alpha x+a, \alpha y+b, \alpha z+ c)&=(\alpha y+b, \alpha x+a)=\alpha(y,x)+(b,a)\\&=\alpha T(x,y,z)+T(a,b,c)=\alpha T(u)+T(v) 
\end{align}
the row of the matrix $A$ is by definition contracted by calculating $T(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is  the canonical basis.
so 
$$
T(e_1)=T(1,0,0)=(0,1)\\
T(e_2)=T(0,1,0)=(1,0)\\
T(e_3)=T(0,0,1)=(0,0)\\
$$ 
so your matrix $A$ will be 
$$
A=\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and you can verifies that $A(x,y,z)=T(x,y,z)=(y,x)$

b) your answer is correct because

> $T$ is linear $\implies$ $T(0)=0$

If fact $T(0)=T(0+0)=T(0)+T(0)$

so $S(0)=(0,1)\neq (0,0)$ so $S$ is not linear.

Comment: How do you go from $T(\alpha x + a, \alpha y + b, \alpha z + c)$ to $(\alpha y + b, \alpha z + c)$?

Comment: Definition of $T$.

Comment: by definition $T(x,y,z)=(y,z)$

Comment: Wait, do you mean $T(x,y,z) = (y,x)$? @Hamza

Comment: Why are you saying $T(x,y,z) = (y,z)$ Where are you getting that information?

Comment: you have right it was a mistake i will fix it now @Yusha

Comment: Thank you so much @Hamza for your patience and help

Answer (score 1):

To show that $T$ is linear just take an arbitrary linear combination $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}$. Apply $T$ to this combination, i.e. $T(a\vec{u}+b\vec{v})$, and show it is equal to $aT(\vec{u})+bT(\vec{v})$. Let $\vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Then, $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix} ax_1+bx_2 \\ ay_1+by_2 \\ az_1+bz_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Apply $T$ to this vector and find out what you get. Compare that to the linear combination $aT(\vec{u})+bT(\vec{v})$.

For the matrix, think of the definition of matrix multiplication. You know the matrix representing $T$ should be 2 rows and 3 columns. The first row of should be $(0, 1, 0)$. What about the second?

Your answer is correct for the second part because a linear transformation must map $\vec{0}$ to $\vec{0}$. This is a one-way implication, meaning that if a mapping takes $\vec{0}$ to $\vec{0}$ it does not mean it's linear.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. What is $a$ and $b$? Are they just arbitrary numbers I can pick?

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary numbers but you don't pick values for them, you leave them arbitrary. By showing things are equal without ever plugging in values for $a$ and $b$ we show that the equality holds for all $a$ and $b$. Work out what $T(a\vec{u}+b\vec{v})$ and $aT(\vec{u})+bT(\vec{v})$ are.

Comment: So.. $T(a\vec{u} + b\vec{v}) = aT(\vec{u}) + bT(\vec{v})$ so that means its a linear transformation right?

Comment: That's what you want to show, that is the literal definition of a linear transformaton. Just writing it doesn't show it's true, though.

Comment: $T(a\vec{u} + b\vec{v}) = T(a\vec{y} + b\vec{x})$ then so yes it is a linear transformation? The way to "prove" it is **extremely** unclear and confusing to me

Comment: You can explicitly compute $T(a\vec{u}+b\vec{v})$. What is it? You can explicitly compute $aT(\vec{u})+bT(\vec{v})$. What is it? Notice that $T$, $\vec{u}$, and $\vec{v}$ have all been defined already. You should be able to compute the above by applying the definition of $T$.

Comment: I've computed them and found that they are the same so it is a linear transf.

Comment: Thank you Tony for your patience and help

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you figured it out.